# UTF 8 string(russian encoding) errors, iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, utf-8

```
for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
    {
        for (NSMutableString *name in [statuses objectForKey:@"response"]) 
        {

            NSMutableString *name1=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",name];
            const char *utf8name=[name1 UTF8String];
            NSMutableString *name_str=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCString:utf8name encoding:4]; 

            [list_names addObject:[NSMutableString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",name_str]];
            [name_str release];
        }
NSLog(@"%@",list_names);

(
    "{\n    \"first_name\" = \"\\U0421\\U0442\\U0430\\U0441\";\n    \"last_name\" = \"\\U0411\\U044b\\U043a\\U043e\\U0432\";\n    uid = 41182952;\n}",
    "{\n    \"first_name\" = Victoria;\n    \"last_name\" = Violette;\n    uid = 56292826;\n}",
    "{\n    \"first_name\" = \"\\U042e\\U043b\\U044f\";\n    \"last_name\" = \"\\U0411\\U0438\\U043b\\U043e\\U0448\\U043d\\U0438\\U0447\\U0435\\U043d\\U043a\\U043e\";\n    uid = 73743149;\n}",
    "{\n    \"first_name\" = \"\\U041a\\U0430\\U0440\\U0438\\U043d\\U0430\";\n    \"last_name\" = \"\\U041f\\U0435\\U0440\\U043e\\U0432\\U0430\";\n    uid = 77001828;\n}",
    "{\n    \"first_name\" = \"\\U0415\\U043b\\U0438\\U0437\\U0430\\U0432\\U0435\\U0442\\U0430\";\n    \"last_name\" = \"\\U041b\\U0435\\U0431\\U0435\\U0434\\U0435\\U043d\\U043a\\U043e\";\n    uid = 90720663;\n}",
    "{\n    \"first_name\" = \"\\U041c\\U0430\\U0440\\U0438\\U043d\\U0430\";\n    \"last_name\" = \"\\U0414\\U0440\\U044b\\U0433\\U0430\";\n    uid = 91646824;\n}",
    "{\n    \"first_name\" = \"\\U0412\\U0438\\U043a\\U0430\";\n    \"last_name\" = \"\\U041a\\U0430\\U0440\\U0430\\U0431\\U0446\\U043e\\U0432\\U0430\";\n    uid = 96178026;\n}",
    "{\n    \"first_name\" = Pink;\n    \"last_name\" = Angel;\n    uid = 97996978;\n}",
    "{\n    \"first_name\" = \"\\U0410\\U043d\\U043d\\U0430\";\n    \"last_name\" = \"\\U0420\\U043e\\U0434\\U0438\\U043d\\U0430\";\n    uid = 133053290;\n}"
)}
```

English text displays normal, but russian not.How to fix it?
I thinked that the problem in UTF8, but I change encoding to UTF8 and no changes.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", list_names);
```

it calls the `-description` method for `list_names`.  For an `NSArray`, this prints the array out as it would appear in an old text plist.  The `%@` format specifier is normally used for debugging purposes when it's not being used for strings.

The code converts to UTF-8 and then back to an `NSString`.  This round trip operation serves no purpose.

The code uses `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj]`.  This is equivalent to calling `[obj description]`.

The code iterates with a variable that is not used in the loop body.

Here is a quick suggestion:

```
for (NSDictionary *response in [status objectForKey:@"response"]) {
    NSString *firstName = [response objectForKey:@"first_name"];
    NSString *lastName = [response objectForKey:@"last_name"];
    [list_names addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", last_name, first_name]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", list_names);
```

Comment: this code also doesn't works(
    "\U041a\U0443\U0440\U0431\U0430\U0442\U043e\U0432\U0430, \U041b\U0435\U0440\U0430",
    "\U0428\U043c\U0443\U0440\U0430\U0442\U043e\U0432\U0430, \U041d\U0430\U0441\U0442\U044e\U0448\U043a\U0430",
    "Sokolchenko, Rita",
    "Mirnyi, Vlad",
    "\U041b\U0435\U0431\U0435\U0434\U0435\U043d\U043a\U043e, \U0415\U043b\U0438\U0437\U0430\U0432\U0435\U0442\U0430",
    "\U0418\U0432\U0430\U0449\U0435\U043d\U043a\U043e, \U041b\U0451\U0448\U0430"
)